# JSF Open dialog on value change

Tags: jsf, events, primefaces

I have multiple views in my web application. On each view, I need to check for a "change event". As soon as a value is changed (without submit), I want to set a boolean in my bean true. Is this possible? There are many inputs so a  on every component would be annoying.

I'm working on a Wildyfly server and use Primefaces 6.2, JSF 2.2.

Thx and greetings!

Comment: Try to use <p:remoteCommand > to change the value in a event as onchange.

Comment: in that case i would have to add this to every editable component in all views - thats why i'm looking for a workaround

Answer (score 0):

I think that can be achieved with jquery + remote command, for example:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
             $(document).ready(function () {
                 $(".ui-input").on('change', function (event) {
                    setBooleanValue()
                 });
             });

         </script>
```

and then the remoteCommand which will trigger a method on managed bean responsible for setting the boolean value:

```
    <h:form>
       <p:remoteCommand name="setBooleanValue" action="#{myBeann.callMethodToSetBoolean}"/>
    </h:form>
```

The remoteCommand will be called on every (primefaces) input change.

Also if you have **ajax** updates on the page you'll need to re-register the jquery change event on inputs after the ajax call:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".ui-input").on('change', function (event) {
            setBooleanValue()
        });
    });

    $(document).on("pfAjaxComplete", function () {
        $(".ui-input").on('change', function (event) {
            setBooleanValue()
        });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: will this work for all editable primefaces components? for example selectonemenu or datatable?

Comment: Just adjust the selector, e.g $(".ui-input, .ui-selectonemenu")

Comment: unfortunately this solution causes to much perfomance issues =/